# How do if statements return values?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to shift all letters to the right one while excluding non-letters. This operation seems so simple I can't wrap my head around why this is not returning me values + 1. I come from Python background and new to Ruby, if I am making a very obvious mistake please forgive me.

```
def rotate(letter_num)
    if letter_num + 1 == 123
      return 97
    elsif letter_num + 1 == 91
      return 65
    elsif !(letter_num =~ /[a-zA-Z]/)
      return letter_num
    else
      return letter_num + 1
    end
end
```

Example 1:
Actual result:

```
rotate(60)
=> 60
```

Expected result:

```
rotate(60)
=> 61
```

Example 2:

Actual result:

```
rotate(123)
=> 123
```

Expected result:

```
rotate(123)
=> 97
```

Comment: With an example input, please explain the problem.. only code doesn't make any sense

Comment: Also example output, and expected output.

Comment: What is this line supposed to be doing `!(letter_num =~ /[a-zA-Z]/)`? It currently resolves to true for everything I've tried. (I'm not familiar with `=~`)

Comment: @Cereal: It's the pattern match operator. AFAIK it never yields anything but nil for Fixnums, but it's used to Regexp match strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have to do with how if-expressions work. What's happening is that the expression `!(letter_num =~ /[a-zA-Z]/)` is true for all of those numbers (because they are numbers rather than strings that contain letters), so you're hitting the `return letter_num` line every time.